# Loop through Dynamic Associative array in Perl?

Tags: html, arrays, perl

I am working on some html documents each one with a list of links, and each link when opened has another list of links, however, each list of links might have links from another list, and i have a hash array with just one link in the beginning `my %list = ($link1 => 1);`, what i do so far is open the existing link and loop through all links in the html document (the following code show the variable $tree that had parsed the html content of the link) :

```
for my $node ( $tree->look_down('_tag' => 'a'))
{
next unless $node;

my $link = $node->attr('href');
unless(exists($list{$link}))
{
    $list{$link} = 1;
}
}
```

Now what i want to do is loop through the hash table as it is being feed each time a new link appears.

I hope i have been clear.

EDIT :

[This](http://www.fifostream.tv/film-en-streaming-parker-720p-AFFJXYGFKK.html) is the page I am getting the links from, when choosing one link from the list, sometimes there are links that are not found in another list, so to be sure i have all the links from the different lists, i Open each link and loop through the list, when there is a new link i add it to the hash array.

to be more clear, my algo is as follow :

- I have a hash table with one link `my %list = ($link1 => 1);`, the value 1 means that the link hasnt been opened and thus, i still didnt check the list of links it has.
- once i do get the list of links, I loop through it and check if the hash array doesnt have one of the links i am looping through
- once I finished looping through the above list, the first link i opened will be updated to 2 `$list{$link}=2` and pass to the following link in the hash table (have in mind that the hash array is being feed each time a new link is found)

Thanks in advance

Comment: To be honest personally I don't understand the question/problem ! :/ If it's not only me could you please rephrase?

Comment: What is **Dynamic** about the problem? Please show the data structures involved. What do the various lists of links look like? Is the `$list{$link} = 1` the code that makes a new link appear? Where in the code do you want to loop through a hash and is `%list` the hash you want to loop through?

Comment: I hope it is somehow understandable now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you want to build a crawler, and avoid visiting any link twice. Therefore, you are adding visited links to a hash. Is this correct?

Your problem seems to be that you add the new links to the seen links before you actually visited them, thus having difficulty finding them again. In this case, hashes are the wrong data structure. Use a hash to register seen links (in order to avoid duplicates), but use an array for a queue of unvisited links:

```
my @queue = ('http://www.example.com/');     # start with at least one link in the queue
my %seen = ('http://www.example.com/' => 1); # this link is "known"

# look at the next link in the queue
while (defined(my $url = shift @queue)) {
  my $tree = some_magic($url);

  # 1. extract all <a>s
  # 2. extract the href value, skipping <a>s that don't have a href
  # 3. add them to the queue if not yet seen
  for my $link ($tree->look_down(...)) {
    my $href = $link->attr('href');
    next unless length $href;
    next if $seen{$href};

    $seen{$href} = 1;
    push @queue, $href;
  }
}
```

The inner loop can be also written as

```
push @queue,
  grep { length($_) and not $seen{$_}++ }
  map  { $_->('href') }
  $tree->look_down(...);
```

There are some remaining issues:

- Some URLs can look different, but be equivalent. E.g. space is often encoded as `+` or `%20`. Normalize the URL to avoid this.
- URLs can have a fragment part `#foo` that is not transmitted to the server. You should probably remove that fragment before testing if you have already seen the URL.
- It is impolite to hammer a server with requests. A `sleep` of a few seconds between each request is better.
- The internet is a vast place. You should probably limit the depth of your search, and record it along with the URL in the `@queue`:

  ```
  my @queue = (['http://www.example.com/', 5]); # start with depth 5
  ...
  while(my $item = shift @queue) {
    my ($url, $depth) = @$item;
    ...
    $seen{$href} = 1;
    next if $depth <= 0;
    push @queue, [$href, $depth-1];
    ...
  }
  ```

Comment: This is exactly what i needed :D, I am so sorry for the confusion, thanks a lot for you help and quick answer.